# Unable to access the user session in socket.io by parsing the cookie

Tags: cookies, express, socket.io

I am tring to access the user session into my socket connection in order to accept/refuse it.

The problem is, i do get a `sessionId string` but the session i get with `SessionStore.get()` is `undefined`.

I guess the problem could be that i never "signed" the sessionId after getting it (`data.cookie['connect.sid']`), but i didn't see any way to do it with the `cookie` module.

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var SessionStore = new MongoStore({ db: "test" });
var parseCookie = require('cookie').parse;

app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'test',
        store: SessionStore
    }));

io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['connect.sid'];
        console.log('sessionId: '+data.sessionID);
        SessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
            if (err || !session) {
                console.log('err: '+err);
                console.log('Session: '+session);
                accept('Error', false);
            } else {
                data.session = session;
                accept(null, true);
            }
        });
    } else {
       return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
});
```

Maybe someone see what i am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connect.sid` cookie is formatted into 2 parts with a prefix. The actual session ID part can be extracted with this fragment:

```
rawSid.split(".")[0].slice(2);
```